# How to work around with routers? I want to check if the URI is exisiting like it's controller and action

Tags: php, phalcon-routing, phalcon

I am a newbie in Phalcon PHP and I'm currently developing a CMS.

I am trying to create a blog module where the user can post blog with custom slug like with URL structure.

I am having a problem on routing the URI like I want to check first if the controller or action exists or not. If not, it should redirect to my action handler and check if this is a a blog and if it is not a post it should redirect to 404 page.

I already have a code on my router. I already have a code where it redirects to my view action handle

```
$router->add(
    '/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)',
    [
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'viewPostHandler',
        'posts_category' => 1,
        'posts_slug' => 2
    ]
);
```

So, the code I have already accepts any slug and redirects to  posts/viewPostHandler and pick a volt. But with this router it is affecting the default /:controller/:action router.

Like, index/loginSubmit is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The order routes are registered matters.

If you load a concrete route (`$this->router->addGet('/sample-url')`) before a route with a slug that can match the concrete route (`$this->router->addGet('/[a-z-]')`) it will prioritize the slugged route.

If you reverse the registering order, so in the above example you load `/sample-url` last, it should work.

Relevant part of the [documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/routing) (search for "order"):

> Since you can add many routes as you need using the add() method, the
>   order in which routes are added indicate their relevance, latest
>   routes added have more relevance than first added. Internally, all
>   defined routes are traversed in reverse order until Phalcon\Mvc\Router
>   finds the one that matches the given URI and processes it, while
>   ignoring the rest.

Comment: Hi, I tried this already. And made the double wildcard last on my router configuration.. But, still the other links is broken.

Comment: Could you show me the output of `$router->getRoutes()`? Are you sure they're loaded?